# Prove integral of sequence of function uniformly converges

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Show that if $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ and $f_n$ is integrable for each n then **$\int_{a}^{x}f_n(t)dt\to \int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$** uniformly in $x$ on [a,b].

I know how to prove the question **$\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx\to \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$** uniformly in $x$ on [a,b]. [image]

I want to make sure if it is same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly so. Did you understand the proof you have pasted above?
$$
\left|\int_a^x (f_n(t) - f(t))\,dx\right| \leq \int_a^x |f_n(t) - f(t)| \,dt \leq \int_a^b \epsilon/(b-a) \,dt < \epsilon,$$ 
for all $n$ sufficiently large. The last inequality follows from the fact that $|f_n(t) - f(t)|$ is nonnegative.

(I've left out obvious details that are already present in what you've pasted above. )

Comment: can i prove like this way:$\int_{a}^{x}|f_n(t)-f(t)|dx \le \frac{\epsilon}{|b-a|}|a-x|\le\frac{\epsilon}{|b-a|}|a-b|=\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

"I know how to prove the question **$\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx\to \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$** uniformly in $x$ on $[a,b]$."
This is a sequence of numbers so we can not talk about uniform continuity.
I think you can use the same method, just use that $x-a\le b-a$.